# Get Full URL for ActiveStorage image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

The following will return a URL that will work, but is there a better method that doesn't require the concatenation of strings? I do not want to expose the service_url since that URL expires.

```
 root_url + url_for(object.image.variant(resize: '140x140'))
```

Ultimately, I would like to do something like this

```
object.image.variant(resize: '140x140').absolute_url
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the recommended way, but you can use the polymorphic_url helper:

```
polymorphic_url object.image.variant(resize: '140x140')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tom! You're the best!